Newly and dynamically created product variant temporarily displays a price of zero in the cart
TL;DR
Why can newly created product variants be added to the cart but within the cart show a wrong price (i.e. 0.00), only updating to the correct price after a few seconds and a page reload?
Details:
I'm encountering an issue where the cart displays an incorrect price (zero) immediately after adding a product with a dynamically created variant. However, after reloading the cart a few times, the correct price appears.
Steps to Reproduce:

Load a product page.
Execute a script (provided below) to:

Create a new variant with a custom price.
Verify that the correct price is retrievable via Admin and Storefront GraphQL APIs.
Add the product to the cart using the new variant.
Open the cart in a new tab for inspection.



Expected Behavior:
The cart should display the correct price immediately after adding the product.
Actual Behavior:
The cart initially shows a price of zero, but the correct price appears after reloading.
Additional Information:

Theme: Dawn Theme
Customizations: No specific changes to the theme
Variant Creation: Variants are created dynamically because in our final shop the price is based on complex product configurations and pricing rules.
Script used above:

JavaScript
// Constants for improved security and maintainability
const SHOPIFY_DOMAIN = 'https://xxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com';  // Replace with your actual domain
const SHOPIFY_API_VERSION = '2024-07';
const SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Replace with your actual access token (store securely)
const SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' // Replace with your actual access token (store securely)

// Function to execute the GraphQL mutation and update the DOM
async function createProductVariant() {

  // Define the fixed product ID and price
  const productId = "1234756483"; 
  const price = "10.00";
  const compareAtPrice = "18.00";

  // Generate a random name
  const randomName = 'Variant_' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);

  // Prepare the GraphQL mutation with the fixed product ID and price
  const graphql = JSON.stringify({
    query: `
      mutation productVariantsBulkCreate(
        $productId: ID!,
        $variants: [ProductVariantsBulkInput!]!
      ) {
        productVariantsBulkCreate(productId: $productId, variants: $variants) {
          product { id }
          productVariants {
            id
            title
            price
            compareAtPrice
          }
          userErrors {
            field
            message
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      productId: `gid://shopify/Product/${productId}`,
      variants: [
        {
          optionValues: {
            optionName: "Title",
            name: randomName,
          },
          price: price,
          compareAtPrice: compareAtPrice,
          inventoryItem: {
            tracked: false,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });

  try {
    console.log("graphql: ", graphql);
    const response = await fetch(`${SHOPIFY_DOMAIN}/admin/api/${SHOPIFY_API_VERSION}/graphql.json`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN, // Consider using environment variables
      },
      body: graphql
    });
    const result = await response.json();

    // Check for errors
    if (result.errors || result.data.productVariantsBulkCreate.userErrors.length > 0) {
      console.error('GraphQL errors:');
      // Print all user errors
      if (result.errors) {
        result.errors.forEach(error => console.error(` - ${error.message}`));
      }
      if (result.data.productVariantsBulkCreate.userErrors) {
        result.data.productVariantsBulkCreate.userErrors.forEach(error => console.error(` - Field: ${error.field}, Message: ${error.message}`));
      }
      return;
    }

    // Extract the productVariant ID (Global ID format)
    const productVariantGlobalId = result.data.productVariantsBulkCreate.productVariants[0].id;

    // Convert the Global ID to a numeric ID
    const productVariantId = extractNumericId(productVariantGlobalId);


    return productVariantId;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating product variant:', error);
  }
}

// Function to extract the numeric ID from the Global ID
function extractNumericId(globalId) {
  // The globalId is in the format "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/1234567890"
  const parts = globalId.split('/');
  return parts[parts.length - 1];
}

// Function to trigger the button click
function triggerAddToCartButton() {
  const addToCartButton = document.querySelector('.product-form__submit');
  if (addToCartButton) {
    addToCartButton.click();
  } else {
    console.error('Add to Cart button not found.');
  }
}



async function getProductVariantPrice(productVariantId) {
  const graphql = JSON.stringify({
    query: `
      query productVariant($id: ID!) {
        productVariant(id: $id) {
          price
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: productVariantId
    }
  });

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${SHOPIFY_DOMAIN}/admin/api/${SHOPIFY_API_VERSION}/graphql.json`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Shopify-Access-Token': SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN
      },
      body: graphql
    });
    const result = await response.json();

    if (result.errors) {
      console.error('GraphQL errors:', result.errors);
      return null;
    }

    const price = result.data.productVariant.price;
    return price;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching product variant price:', error);
    return null;
  }
}

async function getProductVariantPriceStorefront(productVariantId) {
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token", SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    myHeaders.append("Cookie", "request_method=POST");
    
    const graphql = JSON.stringify({
        query: `
          {
            node(id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/${productVariantId}") {
              ... on ProductVariant {
                id
                price {
                  amount
                  currencyCode
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        variables: {}
      });
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: graphql,
      redirect: "follow"
    };
    
    let response =  await fetch(SHOPIFY_DOMAIN + "/api/2024-07/graphql.json", requestOptions)

    const result = await response.json();

    if (result.errors) {
      console.error('GraphQL errors:', result.errors);
      return null;
    }

    const price = result.data.node.price.amount;
    console.log("price: ", price);
    return price;
}

// Execute the function to create the product variant
const productVariantId = await createProductVariant();
console.log("1. Product Variant created with GraphQL - productVariantId: ", productVariantId);


const price = await getProductVariantPrice("gid://shopify/ProductVariant/" + productVariantId);
console.log('2. The price of the newly created Variant can be retrieved via Admin GraphQL API - price:', price);

const priceFromStorefront = await getProductVariantPriceStorefront(productVariantId);
console.log('3. The price of the newly created Variant can be retrieved via Storefront GraphQL API - price:', priceFromStorefront);


// Update the input element in the DOM with the numeric ID
document.querySelector('input.product-variant-id').value = productVariantId;
// Trigger the "Add to Cart" button
triggerAddToCartButton();
console.log("4. Newly created product variant added to cart ");

console.log("5. open a new tab with the cart in order to check if the price is shown there");
setTimeout(function() {
    window.open(SHOPIFY_DOMAIN+"/cart", '_blank');
  }, 300);


I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the correct price is displayed in the cart immediately after adding a dynamically created variant.
